# Form Elements for mobile website - similar to the selection on jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, mobile

I am currently doing a mobile website for a project. The mobile website will **not** be using  jQuery mobile.

One of the pages is a very large page full of form elements which requires to use all of the features that jQuery Mobile uses, such as: -

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all.html

Are these available to use on html/css websites without using jQuery mobile? Is there a list of features and code for these?

Thanks

Comment: "The mobile website will not be using jQuery mobile." and "a very large page full of form elements which requires to use all of the features that jQuery Mobile uses". Such a paradox.

Comment: Honestly, I'd do everything I could do to be able to use jQuery mobile. You can download the source code for jQuery UI if you want (remember to get the unminified version) and implement that yourself... but what's the point?

Comment: Out of my hands im afraid, i did push for jQuery mobile as ive used it before. However the powers above have decided not to use it, however i need to be able to use all the form elements like jQuery mobile provide, so wondered if there is any plugin or something to replicate these, purely for a mobile website